# Interrupted Quartz Trigger does not resume

Tags: quartz-scheduler

In my project, I am creating an immediate SimpleTrigger that invokes a dummy job (does something that lasts for more than 30 seconds). I've set the misfire policy as MISFIRE_INSTRUCTION_FIRE_NOW and the job requests recovery flag is also set to true.

After the job starts (state transits from READY to RUNNING in Quartz DB store), I intentionally bounce (restart) the entire system and this interrupts the running job. When the system is back to active state, what I see is the interrupted job doesn't re-fire at all.

In our production system, this will hurt badly because any software update would un-intentionally end up interrupting the running jobs at that instance and those won't fire again at all (A critical one-off job would go unfinished causing undesirable ripples in forthcoming jobs). This is highly undesirable from our perspective.

What I want is the interrupted job also fires after the system is back up again (essentially the same behavior is the trigger schedule time was during the system downtime and the policy was MISFIRE_INSTRUCTION_FIRE_NOW). Is there a workaround here?

Answer (score 5):

To do that, you must configure the Job with the option requestRecovey, in Java and Quartz 2.X:

```
JobDetail jd = newJob(job).withIdentity(name, group) //
            .requestRecovery()// ask scheduler to re-execute this job
            .build(); // if it was in progress when the scheduler went down...
```